# Facebook OGraph photo manifest error with Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm facing an issue while sharing a Facebook OpenGraph content in my application. I've carefully read the Facebook developer page which is well documented but I still have this error ...

Here is my code :

```
private void facebookShareWithOpenGraph(final SmartRunFirebase aSmartRun, final StatisticSmartRun stats){

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(aSmartRun.getAffectedCity().getCityPicture())
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();



    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
            .putString("og:title", aSmartRun.getName())
            .putString("og:description", aSmartRun.getDescription())
            .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
            .putInt("fitness:duration:value", stats.getChronoInSecond())
            .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
            .putDouble("fitness:distance:value", (double) stats.getTravelledDistance()/1000)
            .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
            .putDouble("fitness:speed:value", statCalculator.parseInMeterPerSecond(stats.getMediumSpeed()))
            .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("fitness.runs")
            .putObject("fitness:course", object)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();



   // ShareDialog.show(StatsSmartRunsActivity.this, content);
    // initiate share process
    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.show(content);


}
```

And in my manifest

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXXAppID"
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Without adding the picture with .putPhoto everything is fine. But when I  add it, I have a crash to the line **shareDialog.show(content);** :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ContentProvider for this app was not set up in the AndroidManifest.xml, please add com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXXX as a provider to your AndroidManifest.xml file. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android for more info.
```

How is that possible ? It is written in my Manifest ! And how could I share my OpenGraph without Picture if my provider wasn't correctly defined as it is said ?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oookay so ...

I didn't put the provider into the right place in the XML file.

It must be within the application bracket and not outside... !